# How to create script auto run without choose on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, script

I create a script and when I execute it, a dialog show for me choose one option: Run in Terminal, Display, Cancel and Run. I want run it automatically without choose option. Anybody know how ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a launcher.  And it will run or run in terminal depending on what you selected when creating the launcher.  I do not know what version of Ubuntu you have.  I use Ubuntu 10.10

Comment: I use Ubuntu 10.04 LST

Comment: In 10.10 you can create a launcher by right clicking the desktop and choosing "Create Launcher".  I would guess that it is the same in 10.04.  May be different in 11.04's Unity.

Answer (score 0):

You should run your script from the terminal. First change the permissions by typing in "chmod 755 scriptname" and then run it by typing "./scriptname".

Comment: I want to make script, and I want it like icon program, when I double-click it, it run automatically. On windows, I can add parameter into link target of a programming shortcut, but on Linux, I don't know way to do this. Help me.