# How to create script auto run without choose on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, script

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create script auto run without choose on Ubuntu?](https://superuser.com/questions/313339/how-to-create-script-auto-run-without-choose-on-ubuntu)

I create a script and when I execute it, a dialog show for me choose one option: Run in Terminal, Display, Cancel and Run. I want run it automatically without choose option. Anybody know how ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are double clicking on the file form some file explorer. Run it from the command line instead and it should work fine.

If you want to run it from the file explorer, you need to create a launcher:

- right click on the desktop and click 'Create Launcher'
- name the launcher
- put the command you want to run (i.e. your script)